# How to monitor consecutive exceptions in Azure? (Kusto)

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-monitoring, azure-data-explorer

I want to monitor consecutive exceptions.

For example if I get 'X' amount of '500' exceptions in a row, I want it to trigger an action group.

How to write this in Kusto?

I know how to monitor amount of exceptions over a 1min period but I'm a bit stuck on how to monitor consecutive exceptions.

Comment: is it summarize count() by xxx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the query like below:

```
Exceptions
| summarize count() by xxx
```

For more details about summarize operator, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/summarizeoperator).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for setting up a [`custom log alert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-unified-log) on AppInsights

Here is the [`step by step guide`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log) on how to setup

You can use the following query with **[Summarize Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/#summarize-operator)**

```
exceptions
| where timestamp >= datetime('2019-01-01')
| summarize min(timestamp) by operation_Id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know how to do this. I was just wanting to write a custom log analytics query on how to show consecutive exceptions.

Comment: @MattTaylor check above